# Similar to solaries prstart -t command in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rhel, solaris

What is a similar command in Linux for the command from Solaris:

```
prstat -t
```

I am interested to get user vice resource consumption (i.e. memory and processor).

It gives `NPROC UserName SWAP RSS Memory TimeCPU`

Is there any scripts available to generate more or less similar output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`atop`](http://www.atoptool.nl/) and press <kbd>u</kbd> to get the user report. Or just run:

```
atop -u
```

Comment: atop works but on production, it is not allowed to install external rpms/packages. So I can not use that. Please could you suggest something else which I can use or write script by using existing resources on RHEL/OEL.

Comment: @user3134198 Who on earth instituted such a byzantine rule? If it matters that it is installed everywhere, have a virtual package that depends on it installed everywhere (or, if you are using a CM, just put it in there). Not being able to debug issues on production clusters is just straight up dumb.

Comment: Hello Chris! Sorry I could understand your comment. But unfortunately the IT manager at the production level restricted to install any extra packages/rpm. So need to solve by sheel scripts by manipulating top or some other resource meter commands which are shipped with rhel 6 or oel 6.